Differential Ordinary Generating Function
I am given the equation $(1 - 6z + z^2) * F'(z) + (z - 3) * F(z) = 0$, $F(0) = 1$ where $F(z) = \text{summation of} \, a_n * z^n$ and is an ordinary generating function representing the sequence a_n of integers. I have been asked to write down  recurrence satisfied by this sequence and compute $a_n$ for $n \leq 5$. I tried substituting $F(z)$ and $F'(z)$ but after I differentiate $F(z)$ I get summation (Starting from $n=0$) of $(n+1) * a_{n+1} * z^n$ wherein the coefficient is for a higher term since $n+1 > n$. I am quite new to generating functions and don't know how to go from here.

Given
$$ (1 - 6 \, x + x^2) \, F'(x) + (x-3) \, F(x) = 0, \quad F(0) = 1$$
and
$$ F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^n $$
then the goal is to find an expression of the form $ \alpha_{n} \, a_{n+1} - \beta_{n} \, a_{n} + \gamma_{n} \, a_{n-1} = 0$. This is done in the following way.
\begin{align}
0 &= (1 - 6 \, x + x^2) \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \, a_{n} \, x^{n-1} + (x - 3) \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \, a_{n} \, x^{n-1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (6 n + 3) \, a_{n} \, x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) \, a_{n} \, x^{n+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) \, a_{n+1} \, x^n - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (6 n + 3) \, a_{n} \, x^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \, a_{n-1} \, x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [ (n+1) \, a_{n+1} - (6 n + 3) \, a_{n}  + n \, a_{n-1} ] \, x^n. 
\end{align}
From this it is determined that
$$ (n+1) \, a_{n+1} - (6 n + 3) \, a_{n}  + n \, a_{n-1} = 0, \quad \text{with} \,\, a_{0} = 1.$$
Note that $a_{0} = 1$ is obtained from $F(0) = 1$. The first few terms of the series of $F(x)$ is
$$ F(x) = 1 + 3 \, x + 13 \, x^2 + 63 \, x^3 + \cdots. $$
The first order differential equation can be solved exactly and has the solution
$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 6 \, x + x^2}} = 1 + 3 \, x + 13 \, x^2 + 63 \, x^3 + 321 \, x^4 + \cdots. $$
The two methods give results that agree.

Your goal is to get a comprehensible power series on one side of the equation, and zero on the other. The only way a power series converges to the zero function is if each term is zero, so we set each term to zero, which gives us a recurrence.
So, how do we get that power series? We've got multiple power series on the LHS, so we need to combine them to get a single one. However, to combine two power series, we must have the same indices and the same powers.
$$ \sum\limits_{n=0} a_n x^n + \sum\limits_{n=1} b_n x^n = \ ??? $$
$$ \sum\limits_{n=0} a_n x^n + \sum\limits_{n=0} b_n x^{n+1} = \ ??? $$
$$ \sum\limits_{n=0} a_n x^n + \sum\limits_{n=0} b_n x^n = \sum\limits_{n=0} (a_n + b_n) x^n $$
For the first case, we can just evaluate the $n=0$ term in the first summation:
$$ \sum\limits_{n=0} a_n x^n + \sum\limits_{n=1} b_n x^n = a_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1} a_n x^n + \sum\limits_{n=1} b_n x^n = a_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1} (a_n + b_n) x^n $$
Alternatively, if $b_0 = 0$, then there's no harm in just adding the zero term so that you can start that summation at $n=0$:
$$ \sum\limits_{n=0} a_n x^n + \sum\limits_{n=1} b_n x^n = \sum\limits_{n=0} a_n x^n + \sum\limits_{n=0} b_n x^n = \sum\limits_{n=0} (a_n + b_n) x^n $$
For the second case, we can redefine the index so that the powers match. Let $k = n+1$, then
$$ \sum\limits_{n=0} b_n x^{n+1} = \sum\limits_{k=1} b_{k-1}x^k $$
which turns it into an instance of the first case, so we follow through:
$$ \sum\limits_{n=0} a_n x^n + \sum\limits_{n=0} b_n x^{n+1} = a_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1} a_n x^n + \sum\limits_{n=1} b_{n-1} x^n = a_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1} (a_n + b_{n-1}) x^n $$
Of course, we renamed $k$ back to $n$ to match the first summation, but that's purely cosmetic.
With these tools in hand, we can consolidate the LHS by first distributing the summations across the coefficient polynomials, then redefining the indices to get the powers to match, evaluating the lowest index terms and/or adding zero terms to get the indices to match, and finally combining the resulting summations.
